# How to put my FB code in a block?

Tags: blocks

Im noob in Drupal and I don't know how can I put the FB code for display the last post in a block. I'd create a block with php code text format, but doesn't work, the block does not render the code.
This is the code from FB, if I put it into a plain html file it works fine

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/mysupersite" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="320" data-height="450" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"></div>
```

How can I put this into a block?
I'd created a block--fb.tpl.php cloning the block.tpl.php and pasted the code but this doesn't work either.
This is for not use the FB module because I should create an app and FB request my data and I don't want an app, just render the last post of the profile
can someone give me some gide with this?
Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 6):

if you using ckeditor firstPut your block **text format** on `FULL HTML` then   click on `soruce`  and finally paste your markups there.

[image]

Comment: I already try with full html. When I try with full html text format I get the code in plain text in the right sidebar. 
I have ckeditor activated as text editor and when I paste the code in the block ckeditor renders the code in plain text :(

Comment: @bug273 simple solution  first put ckeditor in source view then paste your markup there,
another solution is  disable load ckeditor for this block ( or for block edition ) page.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative way if you love coding...

You can create module for fb add block.

module name : custom

```
function custom_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['add_fb'] = array(
    'info' => t('Add fb'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implement hook_block_view().
 */
function custom_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
      case 'add_fb':      
        $block['content'] = t('<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk"));</script>

<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/mysupersite" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="320" data-height="450" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"></div>');
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```

Now you can see a block on "admin/structure/block" named as "Add fb". Place the block where ever you want.

Comment: Thank you so much dude! It works fine! 
I'd create the module and in Chrome it works fine, but in FF doesn't work, but is a step to get the FB working on my site.
Thanks again!

Comment: this solution will work but it's not straightforward and usual method for putting some html markup  in block content  ;)